# Не получается задать ширину для активного слайда Swiper

Tags: javascript, html, css, слайдер, swiper

Макетом предусмотрен такой вариант слайдера:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Слайды имеют ширину 1360px, но если даже задать её стилем, появляется такая дрянь:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
из за которой результат немного не такой:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Моя инициализация сейчас:

```
<script>
                        var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-productions', {
                            slidesPerView: 2,
                            spaceBetween: 115,
                            centeredSlides: true,
                            loop: true,
                            slideActiveClass: 'swiper-slide-active-mod',
                            navigation: {
                                nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
                                prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
                            },
                            keyboard: {
                                enabled: true,
                                onlyInViewport: false,
                            }
                        });
                    </script>
```

В общем то очевидно, что JS файл как-то считает ширину слайдов этих, т.к. он меняет ширину слайдов при изменении ширины самого блока, но найти не удалось.
Пересмотрел API слайдера несколько раз, но почему-то не могу найти ширину самих слайдов...

Может кто знает как задать в параметрах ширину или какой-нибудь скрипт который отрубит стили element.style с данного блока?

Comment: А что за слайдер используете? можно ссылку или название?

Comment: https://swiperjs.com/ Swiper

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос пример кода, как вы его инициализируете

Comment: Добавил, смотрите :)

Comment: а у вас есть другие скрипты на странице?пробовали воспроизвести это в "вакуме"?

Comment: возможно всё портит `slidesPerView` тк он пытается впихнуть 2 слайда в блок

Comment: Он не портит, это задумка такая, которая представлена в демо версиях на сайте самого Swiper'a. Там в принципе ничего не портится, просто слайдер изначально задуман адаптивным, из за чего в JS скрипте слайдера есть высчет ширины центрального блока.

Comment: slidesPerView: 'auto' поставь

Comment: Огонь, добавляйте как ответ, отмечу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ: slidesPerView: 'auto'

kost1k в комментариях ответил.